# Replace all quotes with escaped quotes and vice versa

Tags: substitute, replace

I am trying to replace all quotes (") with escaped quotes (\") and simultaneously all escaped quotes with normal quotes.

I found the following solution to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578549/easiest-way-to-swap-occurrences-of-two-strings-in-vim) for swapping 'foo' to 'bar' and vice versa:

```
:%s/\v(foo|bar)/\={'foo':'bar','bar':'foo'}[submatch(0)]/g
```

but I cannot translate it to my particular case.

The problem being that every escaped quote contains also a normal quote.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

PS: I want to avoid first replacing all escaped quotes with a different (and hopefully unique) pattern, then replacing all remaining normal quotes with escaped quotes, and then replacing the different pattern with normal quotes - but rather do it in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to use the method you found without issue. Perhaps you missed something with the escaping.

```
%s/\v(\\"|")/\={'\"':'"','"':'\"'}[submatch(0)]/
```

I "escape the escape" in the substitution pattern but not in the dictionary since the latter uses single quotes within which the text is interpreted literally.

**Update:** FYI, you can simplify the pattern a little, in this particular case, by using `\\\?"` (though that strays from the generalized solution that you found).